# Loading shapefile in GeoDjango and displaying it in admin section?

Tags: qgis, geodjango

I am trying to load a `.shp` file in GeoDjango Admin. As a newbie I followed their [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) and based on that I am trying to load my own shapefile. No errors are being shown but I can't see my shapefile being loaded. All I can see is a `world map` but I can see attributes related to my shapefile.

Here is the code:

`load.py`

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from .models import TestGeo

testgeo_mapping = {
    'state_n': 'STATE_N',
    'admin_stat': 'ADMIN_STAT',
    'geom': 'MULTIPOLYGON',

}

state_shp = os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'STATE.shp'),
)

def run(verbose=True):
    lm = LayerMapping(TestGeo, state_shp, testgeo_mapping, transform=False)
    lm.save(strict=True, verbose=verbose)
```

`models.py`

```
class TestGeo(models.Model):
    state_n = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    admin_stat = models.IntegerField()
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_n
```

Output:
[image]

Output of `python manage.py ogrinspect forest/data/STATE.shp TestGeo --srid=4326 --mapping --multi`:

```
class TestGeo(models.Model):
    state_n = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    admin_stat = models.IntegerField()
    geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)


# Auto-generated `LayerMapping` dictionary for TestGeo model
testgeo_mapping = {
    'state_n': 'STATE_N',
    'admin_stat': 'ADMIN_STAT',
    'geom': 'MULTIPOLYGON',
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

`shapefile` is completely fine I have plotted it using `matplotlib` and also inspected it in `QGIS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this will answer your question but when I first started using geodjango the I had problems importing both the regular django models `from django.db import models` and the gis django models `from django.contrib.gis.db import models`

Give this a try:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels

class TestGeo(models.Model):
    state_n = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    admin_stat = models.IntegerField()
    geom = gismodels.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
```